# choose a file after choosing a file using jfilechooser

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I want to take input from JFileChooser for multiple file types.
But the problem is I need the first file path as an input in the else part of second file selection

```
        `open jfilechooser to select a file 
        if(type1 selected){
        //do something            
        }else if(type 2 selected){
         //do something
        }
         `
```

The problem is, if type 2 is selected, then I need the user to **SELECT A FILE OF TYPE 1 ALSO**. I tried to do this by opening another JFileChooser inside the if else conditions but to no avail.

I also tried using `filechooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);` and then storing the file paths (according to extensions) in different string variables(using individual if statements *not if-else*), but somehow that doesn't work as well.
How can I make user select another file of type 1 after they have chosen a file of type 2?

P.S: The user can also select type 1 file without any requirement for type 2 file.

Comment: I don't think doing it all in a `JFileChooser` would help here since that's not what the component is meant for and users will have a hard time understanding it. Better let the user select a file and if they selected a file of type 2 (after closing the file chooser and thus confirming the selection) then open a popup to tell them they need a type 1 as well.

Comment: But the operation performed for type 2 selection needs files of both type open. If I close the filechooser, will it not automatically close the file of type 1? Should I save the filepath to a variable and then open them afterwards in a whole new operation?

Comment: Well, if you choose a file that won't open the file anyway but just return a handle/reference to that file. So store it, request another and then run your operation on both.

Comment: the file path storing part is clear to me, but how do I request the other ? after closing the jfilechoose, then open another jfilechooser? i know i sound dumb but im new to it. Your help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, just open another JFileChooser or maybe just display an info popup first and open the JFileChooser once the user closed that popup (or if the user confirmed it if you use a confirm dialog instead).

Comment: Thank you very much @Thomas . It worked well. :D